# CSRF token missing or invalid

Tags: django, django-csrf

I have this error:

> "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

and according to many answers, this is the way to fix it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/order/'+orderid+'/',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"
    }
});
```

However, in my case, it doesn't. I always get that HTTP 403 error. I am sure the token gets sent, Firebug shows me `csrfmiddlewaretoken=jI8P6LfZ1p1OqIv3ikOU1VPFePjFjFnD` in the `PUT` request.

**Edit** When using `POST` as verb, it works as expected.

Comment: I normally use jQuery's `serialize()` to post my data to a view. I really don't know for sure, but I wonder if having the csrf token serialized makes a difference.

Comment: Where is that code? Rather than referencing "many answers", you should perhaps look at the [extremely comprehensive documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) for managing CSRF with Ajax.

Comment: When using `POST`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to get CSRF Token from cookies as mentioned in Documentation.

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

**Then add it to AJAX header:**

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

After these simple write your AJAX requests. CSRF header will be added automatically.

**In your case:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/order/' + orderid + '/',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {}
});
```

**SEE**, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/order/'+orderid+'/',
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
    },
    data: {}
});
```